# Merging 2 Dataframes in Pandas with int values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I got 2 Pandas Dataframes which looks like this:

existing_balance =

| Name | Coins Won |
| --- | --- |
| echo | 250 |
| fives | 250 |
| rex | 500 |

new_deposits =

| Name | Coins Won |
| --- | --- |
| echo | 500 |
| hunter | 1000 |
| kix | 250 |

The final output should look like:

| Name | Coins Won |
| --- | --- |
| echo | 750 |
| fives | 250 |
| hunter | 1000 |
| kix | 250 |
| rex | 500 |

What I tried:

```
existing_records = existing_balance.to_dict(orient="records")
new_records = new_deposits.to_dict(orient="records")

for new_entry in new_records:
    for existing_entry in existing_records:
        if existing_entry["Name"] == new_entry["Name"]:
            existing_entry["Coins Won"] += new_entry["Coins Won"]
```

So that works of the names match, but I can't seem to think of an "if" or "else" that could accommodate the entries that don't already have existing accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two dataframes, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `Name` column and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```py
pd.concat([existing_balance, new_deposits]).groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
      Name  Coins Won
0    echo         750
1   fives         250
2     rex         500
3  hunter        1000
4     kix         250
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas-dataframe-add) with `fill_value=` parameter:

```py
x = df1.set_index('Name').add(df2.set_index('Name'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
     Name  Coins Won
0    echo      750.0
1   fives      250.0
2  hunter     1000.0
3     kix      250.0
4     rex      500.0
```